# Where is the WriteInteger / WriteStream methods gone in Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy

i was viewing an open-source code to learn how to use Indy component in Delphi in [this](http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/l/aa012004a.htm) link, and i've noticed some nice methods, but i get ide error's complaining that it does not exist, i am asking this just to make sure, were they available in old version of the Indy, and if so, what is their replacement in the newer version of Indy in Delphi XE ? thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you are looking at was written for Indy 9.  XE ships with Indy 10 instead.  A lot of things were re-written in Indy 10.  Most notably:

1. `TIdPeerThread` was replaced with `TIdContext`, and context management was decoupled from the parent thread (`TIdPeerThread` is a `TThread` descendant, but `TIdContext` is not).
2. most of the reading/writing methods that were in `TIdTCPConnection` in Indy 9 were moved to `TIdIOHandler` in Indy 10, and most writing methods were also renamed into `Write()` overloads.

So what you are looking for are `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Integer)`, `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(TStream)`, etc.

Comment: When i saw all those Write() overloads, i had a feeling about that.. :D

also, i still get this AContext: TIdContext as a param in the Execute event of the idTcpServer.

Comment: Hey, just a question, lets say i create the instance inside a TThread, inside the thread's Execute procedure, do i need to do a message loop ? just like the one you showed me when using TServer/ClientSocket... my guess is that it is not a message-based component... or is it ?

Comment: Like I said, `TIdPeerThread` in Indy 9 was replaced with `TIdContext` in Indy 10, so you will have `TIdContext` parameters in server event handlers. And no, you do not need a message loop when using Indy in worker threads, as Indy is not message based. Also, keep in mind that `TIdTCPServer` creates its own threads internally for each client connection, so make sure your event handlers are using thread-safe code.

Comment: Another question, inside the OnExecute, i have either IOHandler and Socket, what's the difference and which one is the default one to use ? to me they look the same.

seriously, where can i find documentation about this Indy component and about all of its classes/methods ?

Comment: for indy 10 tcp server you can use  http://sourceforge.net/projects/indy10clieservr/   demo samples

Comment: When the `TIdTCPConnection.IOHandler` property points to a `TIdIOHandlerSocket`-derived object, the `TIdTCPConnection.Socket` property points at the same object, otherwise it is nil instead. This is a kind of shorthand that avoids having to type-cast the `IOHandler` every time socket-specific functionality needs to be accessed, particularly the `TIdIOHandlerSocket.Binding` property. General I/O code should use the `IOHandler` property directly as that allows for handling other types of I/O, not just sockets.

Comment: [Official documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/) is on Indy's website, but it is not up-to-date with all of the new code that has been added to Indy 10 in the past few years, but it is a start.

Comment: how can i get this (http://borland.public.delphi.internet.winsock.narkive.com/I98iv5A8/sending-messages-data-from-tidtcpserver-to-all-connected-tidtcpclients) working in Idny 10 ?

Comment: Replace `Threads` with `Contexts`, `TIdPeerThread` with `TIdContext`, and `Connection.Write` with `Connection.IOHandler.Write`.